# Stopping Siblings interfering with mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently using the "interactive_bg" plugin to create a parallax effect on an image using two images to create the illusion of depth.

Plugin website: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_bg_demo.html

```
            <section id="header" class="header-image bg header-image-back" data-ibg-bg="img/case.study.images/project.images/example.project/header/example_header_back.png">

                <div id="header-image-front" class="header-image bg" data-ibg-bg="img/case.study.images/project.images/example.project/header/example_header_front.png"></div>

                <div id="header-txt-cont">

                    <div id="header-client" class="six-col col">Panasonic</div>
                    <div id="header-date" class="six-col col">June 14</div>    

                    <h1>Raising High The Union Flag</h1>
                    <h5>Social & PR. Creative Design</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed neque est. Proin dictum ante ut ullamcorper convallis. Phasellus auctor in eros vitae feugiat.</p>

                </div>

            </section>
```

The issue that I'm having is that the text positioned absolutely in the center of the screen is causing the mouse events to stop whilst the cursor is over "#header-txt-cont" and essentially pausing the parallax effect. Here's an image of the layout to give you a better idea of how it's being rendered, (man is #header-image-front, TVs .header-image-back):

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I can stop this happening without having to go into the plugin script and edit it extensively, I'd like that to be my last resort.

Comment: It seems to work fine when over the text in the plugin demo site. Do you have `stopPropagation` or `return false` in an event handler on the elements holding the text?

Comment: It works fine with just one "layer" for me too - the issue is adding the #header-front-image presumably because this is a sibling "#header-txt-cont" and so it stops the mouse move events. Since the "header-image-back" is a parent of the text that seems to be fine.